# how to place an overlay screen in flutter app and ask user to payment pop-up to view courses?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**how to ask users for purchase the teaching course modules with an overlay screen with pop-up payment gateway in flutter app?**

1. user can see the screen content but cannot access it.
2. the screen should ask for pop-up menu to purchase the course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `AlertDialog` widget is the one you are looking for.

You can find an example as well as code here : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html